# sudo apt-get install apache2

Tags: updates

I tried to install apache2 with

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Why am i seeing this

```
E: Type 'gpg' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list
E: Type 'gpg' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace content of the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list` with the single line `deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/` - just execute to do this:

```
echo "deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list
```

Next do apt update & upgrade:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

And finally install Apache:

```
sudo apt install apache2
```

Answer (score -1):

Incorrect content of file /etc/apt/source.list.d/sublime-text.list
First line.

```
cp /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list.backup
sed 1d -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list
```

Comment: user@a2shish:~$ /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list.backup
bash: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list.backup: No such file or directory
user@a2shish:~$ sed 1d -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list

Comment: You missed `cp` in first command.

The second command removed first line from /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list . The conntent of this file was incorrect, so apt was not able to correctly install apache.
Try removing the file, and then execute
     apt update ;  apt install apache2